# Get exact definition of function from invocation which is defined in interface but implemented at multiple locations in C# using Roslyn

Tags: c#, symbols, roslyn, analysis

I saw there are lots of questions asked on this topic (C#, Roslyn, Find References and Definitions). But I still not got answer for what I want. Here is explanations.
I have interface:

```
public interface IRepository {      
    IEnumerable<X> Abc(long customerIdentity, ...);        
}
```

Now, this interface in implemented by on class like:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase : IRepository {
 public virtual IEnumerable<X> Abc(long customerIdentity, long? associatedOrderIdentity, ...) { ... }      
}
```

Since this is abstract class, then other classes may have redefined this method as this method is virtual. Also, interface can have property with other interface as well.

```
public sealed class CustRepository : RepositoryBase {
   public override IEnumerable<X> Abc(long customerIdentity, long? associatedOrderIdentity, ...){ ... }       
}
```

Another thing is here like this

```
public interface IRepositoryManager { 
    IRepository Repository { get; }
}
```

In my class variable is declared like this:
`private IRepositoryManager _repositoryManager;` and I can call method like this:
`this._repositoryManager.Repository.Abc(customerIdentity, ...)`

Here are my questions now.

1. How I get to know which method it will call at run time?. I want this to get the definition/declaration using Roslyn. I can use invocation expression to get this statement.
2. Should I take method from base class which directly implements the interface. Or do I need to see definitions from inheritance chain?.

I found some useful answers from:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361709/roslyn-get-method-declaration-from-invocationexpression)
and here:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459474/find-all-method-calls-for-a-specific-method-using-roslyn)

Please do not close this question as I'm really struggling to get this answer. **Thanks in advance!!**.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have this code to get some of information using Roslyn API's.

```
var syntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var sm = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var semantic = compilation.GetSemanticModel(sm);
                    var invocations = (from d in syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>() select d).ToList();
                    foreach (var invocation in invocations)
                    {
                        // if (!invocation.Expression.ToString().Contains("FindAlertsByLimit") && !invocation.Expression.ToString().Contains("FindAlertsByWindow")) continue;
                        var ms = semantic.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol;
                        if (ms == null) continue;
                        var referencesTo = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(ms, document.Project.Solution).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        Console.WriteLine(referencesTo);
                        var de = SymbolFinder.FindDeclarationsAsync(project, referencesTo.First().Definition.Name, false, SymbolFilter.Member).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToList();
                        Console.WriteLine(de);
                        // other approach
                        IMethodSymbol methodSymbol = semantic.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
                        if (methodSymbol == null) continue;
                        var syntaxReferences = methodSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.ToList();
                        if (!syntaxReferences.Any()) continue;
                        var declaration = syntaxReferences.First().GetSyntax();
                        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(declaration.SyntaxTree);
                        Console.WriteLine(semanticModel.SyntaxTree.FilePath);
}
```

But seems like I'm not getting exact method definition.